# Trouble querying database with php*fixed*

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble selecting my data from a database and displaying it. I have looked at tutorials and i still get the same error. Some help would be appreciated. The error i am getting is couldnt fetch result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("couldnt fetch result");
if($result > 0){
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$username = $rows['username'];
echo $username;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first line does not make any sense. You are just assigning a string. `$result` is not a number (it is either a `resource` or `false`), so you cannot compare it against a number.

Comment: The first line is telling it what to select from the database.

Comment: It's just a string, no need to add "or die ...."

Comment: How would i fix that Sverri?

Comment: You'll have to do a count to check if it's more than 0. Also use pdo or myqli.

Comment: `if ($result !== false)`

Comment: Ok, i will start to use mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do that (assuming got it right connecting to DB, first thing to check !)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `data`"; // data is a reserved keyword, protect it !!!
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("couldnt fetch result"); // potentially diying here
if($result){
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $username = $row['username'];
          echo $username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the very simple problem is that you check if the `$result` is greater then 0. But you get an resource.

```
$conn = mysql_connect.......

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("couldnt fetch result");
if($result){
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $username = $rows['username'];
        echo $username;
    }
}
```

And if you see your die statement you have an error in your SQL Syntax. Its very short but its possible that your table doesn't exist in that database you're trying to connect. I hope you have a connect before and its not your complete code.

You use the old mysql functions. Its better to use MySQLi or PDO.

And `DATA` is a reserved keyword its possible that you get problems if you use it in your query. Rename your table in `prefix_data` for example.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Now the error is "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\formcontrol\search.php on line 30"

Comment: Then your Query is wrong. Your select is very short so then you connect to a database where the data table doesn't exist. Use ` echo mysql_error()`.

Comment: I think this is because **data** is a reserved keyword in SQL. See my answer above.

Comment: Yes you're right i've seen that i have testet that :D and then i've seen the message :D... there are so many keywords that this can happen.

Comment: Well I just run the query with data as column name and it runs just fine without encapsulation.  It is a keyword, but it is not reserved word.  I'm thinking mysql has ability to determine whether it's used as a keyword or not from the context.

Comment: ... which doesn't change the fact that data should be properly encapsulated.

Comment: He has a hint... now he can test and find a solution :) the code is not so long.

Comment: Yup.  My guess, there is something wrong with the code above what's shown, or db connection.

Comment: I got it to work it is because i was encapsulating the table i was trying to select from. I apologize for the trouble i have cause thank you for all of your suggestions

Comment: What did you do exactly ? Didn't catch it

Answer (score 0):

If what you're getting is literally 'couldnt fetch result' it means your `mysql_query()` fails, and `die` statement takes over.  Check your database connection.